# ASANA Direct login from my project

Tags: asana

Can I use Asana Connect to open users asana account in my .NET project if user has logged in using his google account

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Asana Connect works even when the user is authorized via Google - it's actually double OAuth because Google provides an identity to Asana, then Asana provides an identity to your app. This should work the same regardless of the language/framework you use, as long as you handle the normal OAuth interaction with Asana properly.